# Packed data in an unknown format, can anyone identify it?

Tags: xml, json, plaintext, identify, data-formats

I am debugging a program provided to me by someone else, and do not have the source code for it.  It just spat the following string of packed data at me:

```
FAILEDTOBUILD 002[AlternateOption [plain text data] re=[OPTION=YES] newValue[OPTION=NO]]
```

I expected it to be XML, but unless the XML format has changed drastically within the last 2 hours, this is something else.  Can anyone help me identify it?

I did some googling, but it was like trying to squeeze water from a rock.

The software is a jar, so I'm trying to decompile it to see what its doing.  The return value is coming as a plain text string.

Is this even really a format?  The exact data returned has been modified for confidentiality reasons, but I have preserved all non-alphanumeric characters in their exact order, including such discrepancies as the "re" field having an equals sign and the newValue field not having one.

Comment: in what plataform or language is the program?

Comment: The program I received?  It's a jar, so its written in java.  I mentioned that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java component was encountering an error of some sort.  When it does this, it returns a plain text string.  So it was just plain text.